# how to set display member of combo box statically before clicking drop down list at run time

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

I want to display member of combo box(add) in windows form before clicking drop list, the members which I'm trying to display are "Add, delete, clear, modify". But despite of setting display member property equal to "add" from property window statically, I'm unable to see "add" in combo box at run time before clicking drop down list of combo box.

Could anyone please tell me what's wrong I'm doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `SelectedIndex` to `0` in your code and this will select the first item in the list.

```
myComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Comment: Using SelectedIndex in this particular case assumes, that your items will always be in the same order. When at a certain moment in the future somebody changes that order, your whole code will collapse as the user will select edit and your website will delete the item instead. Doing things this way is doomed to introduce logical errors in the future ...

Answer (score 2):

I guess that

```
ComboBoxName.SelectedItem = "Add";
```

should work. You can put this in the Form Load method.

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work as SelectedItem is of type <ListItem> so the code won't even compile

Comment: But this worked with me. Afterall the question is asked on a combobox property. I can assure you that I double checked it before publishing.

Answer (score 1):

```
yourCombo.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

or

```
yourCombo.SelectedItem = "Add";
```

Comment: yourCombo.SelectedValue = "Add"; does not work it is the SelectedItem instead.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, given the fact that you already know what values the dropdownlist will have, you can just say `myComboBox.Text = "Add"`

Have fun coding!